# Refreshing TF2 item server connection without launching game

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

Is there a way to refresh your connection to the tf2 item sever without launching the game?

I bought a few keys a week ago and it says they won't be available to trade until Oct 5th 0700GMT. It is now 1330GMT, and I am still unable to trade the keys.
I've read that one needs to launch the game to refresh the connection to the item server. Is there a way to do this without launching the game?

Comment: Why can't you just launch the game?  Seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: I won't have access to my computer with tf2 installed for awhile, but would like to continue trading.

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't the ideal solution, it did work;
Trading another item will refresh the item server. I traded some steam cards on Scrap.tf and my keys were unlocked.